# The sum of density function (based on histogram) is not equal to 1

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

I'm attempting to generate a density function, but the sum of the components of a generated histogram does not appear to be close to 1.

What is the cause of this and how to make the sum of the density function close (even if not exactly equal) to 1?

Minimal example:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.random.normal(0, 0.5, 1000) # mu, sigma, num
bins = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), num=50) # lower and upper bounds
hist, hist_bins = np.histogram(x, bins=bins, density = True)

print(np.sum(hist))
>>> 10.4614
```

If I'm not specifying the bins edges, the output is smaller but still greater than 1:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.random.normal(0, 0.5, 1000) # mu, sigma, num
hist, hist_bins = np.histogram(x, density = True)

print(np.sum(hist))
>>> 3.1332
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this behavior [is stated in the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html):

> density: bool, optional
>
> If False, the result will contain the number
> of samples in each bin. If True, the result is the value of the
> probability density function at the bin, normalized such that the
> integral over the range is 1. Note that the sum of the histogram
> values will not be equal to 1 unless bins of unity width are chosen;
> it is not a probability mass function.

In addition, a sample is provided showing that the sum of the histograms is not equal to 1.0:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(5)
hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(a, density=True)

print(hist)
# hist --> [0.5, 0. , 0.5, 0. , 0. , 0.5, 0. , 0.5, 0. , 0.5]

print(hist.sum())
# --> 2.4999999999999996

print(np.sum(hist * np.diff(bin_edges)))
# --> 1.0
```

So we can apply this to your code snippet:

```
x = np.random.normal(0, 0.5, 1000) # mu, sigma, num
bins = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), num=50) # lower and upper bounds
hist, hist_bins = np.histogram(x, bins=bins, density=True)

print(hist)

print(np.sum(hist))

print(np.sum(hist * np.diff(hist_bins)))
# --> 1.0
```

In addition, you should think about how you have chosen your bins and make sure that using a `.linspace()` is a reasonable way.